# "Transliterate = False" About TFIBDataset Component

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, fibplus

I am using TFIBDataset component with Delphi 2010.

Whenever I just open a form on which I have kept TFIBDataset component(s) and close the same form without doing any changes, and if try to compare that .dfm file with same file in code repository, I always find the below code for all the "TFIBStringField" field in all the respective TFIBDataset component(s)

```
Transliterate = False
```

I would like to avoid this code coming in .dfm file. How do I stop this, so code comparison becomes easier ?

With Best Regards.

Vishal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, you've updated FIBPlus since last time you opened the form in form designer?

Such behaviour occurs when component properties are added but not given a `default` value. Default values are not saved in dfm-files.

I suggest you check those differences not to change your applications behaviour and then commit them to your repository. You won't be bothered with this property in the future. Though, it could happen for other properties as well.

---

**UPDATE:** I just recovered your question. I took a look into source code and now have a theory, why value of `Transliterate` is reset:

Default value of `Transliterate` is `True` (see *Data.DB.pas*). Therefore, value `True` won't be saved in dfm file. In constructor of `TFIBStringField` (see below) `Transliterate` is set to `False`.

```
constructor TFIBStringField.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
   inherited;
   FDefaultValueEmptyString:=False;
   Transliterate:=False;
end;
```

As the value `True` is not saved in dfm, it won't be set, when the content of dfm is assigned to the instance of `TFIBStringField`.

Comment: Whenever I am loading  "TFIBStringField" fields in the Fields Editor, that time if I see the "Transliterate" property of such field, I see as Transliterate is False i.e. it is supposed to be True which is its default property. It is displaying as "False" means somewhere "False" is set. How do I remove and make it to True, so whenever I load such fields then default value would be True.

Comment: Even if I am making all  "TFIBStringField" fields's Transliterate property to True and saving. After closing and opening the form, again all the  "TFIBStringField" field's Transliterate property value becomes False.

Comment: I recovered your question and added another explanation.

Comment: @ René Hoffmann: Thanks a lot. What is happening is one team is using old version of FIB Plus component in that source code this create constructor is not setting value to False where as in new source code of FIB Plus component it is set exclusively. That's why when one team save their source code they come across this issue.